# How to configure serilog to can be used in a class library that is not an ASP Core project?

Tags: c#, serilog

I have a library in which I would like to use logging, so in the constructor, I am passing a Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger parameter.

The consumer of my library is not an ASP Core porject, in this case, I would like to implement a test to see if the logger works. For the test I am using NUint.

I have read some examples how to configure Serilog to can be used with Microsoft.Extensions.Logging, but all of them is about creating a host in an ASP Core application. But it is not my case.

I have tried this in the Start() method of my test class:

```
_logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
.MinimumLevel.Information()
.WriteTo.File("log.txt",
    rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day,
    rollOnFileSizeLimit: true)
.CreateLogger();
```

But I get an error because my library expectMicrosoft.Extensions.Logging and I get an error.

How could I configure Serilog to can be used as parameter that expects Microsoft.Extensions.Logging?

Thanks.

EDIT: this is my class in which I want to inject the logger.

```cs
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
public class MyServiceApplicationLayer
{

    ILogger _logger;


    public MyServiceApplicationLayer(ILogger<MyServiceApplicationLayer> paramLogger)
    {
        _logger = paramLogger;
    }


    //some methods
}
```

This is the SetUp of my test class in which I try to create an instace of Serilog.

```
ILogger _logger;  

[SetUp]
public void Setup()
{
    _logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .MinimumLevel.Debug()
                .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Information)
                .Enrich.FromLogContext()
                .WriteTo.File("log.txt",
                    rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day,
                    rollOnFileSizeLimit: true)
                .CreateLogger();

    _serviceApplicationLayer = new MyServiceApplicationLayer(_logger);
}
```

Comment: If your lib only uses the logging api abstractions from MS, it should be fairly easy to inject a Serilog logger. But it's hard to tell where it derails with only that little snippet.

Comment: Does your lib use `ILogger` or `ILogger<T>`?

Comment: I have added the consumer class of the lirary (the test class in this case) and the class in which I want to inject the logger. In this case i am using ILogger<T>.